# Subsetting Data - more difficult than usual

Tags: r, if-statement, dataframe, subset

I have a dataset that contains observations from different years. The observation did not start for all in the same year, meaning for example that  some start in year 1996 and some start in 2008.

```
Element 1 | 4.1 | 2018
Element 1 | 3.9 | 2017
Element 1 | 3.4 | 2016   
..........|.....| ....    
Element 1 | 2.1 | 1996 
Element 2 | 2.1 | 2018
Element 2 | 1.0 | 2017
..........|.....| ....
Element 2 | 1.0 | 2008
```

Now, I want to have a list that contains only observations which start from 2006 on. This means that this list would contain element 1 but not element 2.

My first approach was to use the command

```
subset(mydata, year > 2006)
```

but this did not work since it includes element 2 as it starts in 2008. I am stuck here. I want to tell R to subset the data only if the condition that the element was observed in years 2006 till 2018 is fulfilled. How should I approach this?

Comment: Can you show your expected results? Do you want all rows from each element that meets the condition that it has observations in all years from 1996 - 2018?

Comment: `subset(mydata,as.logical(ave(year,group,FUN=function(w)any(w<=2006) & any(w>2006))))`???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This `lapply` statement will check each Element to make sure it has an observation from each of a set of years. If every year is accounted for, then it will return the `group` name of that Element, and you can use that to select the rows containing that Element using normal bracket notation:

```
elements <- unlist(lapply(unique(mydata$group), function(x) {
    if (all(c(1996, 2016, 2017, 2018) %in% mydata[mydata$group == x, 'year'])) {
        return(x)
    }
}))

mydata[mydata$group %in% elements, ]

      group value year
1 Element 1   4.1 2018
2 Element 1   3.9 2017
3 Element 1   3.4 2016
4 Element 1   2.1 1996
```

Or if you only want to return years after 2006:

```
mydata[mydata$group %in% elements & mydata$year > 2006, ]

      group value year
1 Element 1   4.1 2018
2 Element 1   3.9 2017
3 Element 1   3.4 2016
```

In your final model, just replace the list of years with:

```
seq.int(2006, 2018)
```

to get a list of all years between 2006 and 2018. I limited it for this example because the sample data only showed a subset of years

To match, an Element must have an observation for every year in the list of years, but having additional years (for example if Element1 also had an observation from 1934) are not a problem.

If you reverse the order of the `%in%` expression, it will check to make sure that every year in the Element is represented in the set of years (but missing years are not a problem)

To ensure both conditions, just use an `&` to join the 2 statements.

Data:

```
mydata <- structure(list(group = c("Element 1", "Element 1", "Element 1",
                                   "Element 1", "Element 2", "Element 2", "Element 2"),
                         value = c("4.1","3.9", "3.4", "2.1", "2.1", "1", "1"),
                         year = c("2018", "2017","2016", "1996", "2018", "2017", "2008")),
                    row.names = c(NA, -7L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 1):

Using base R only:

```
newdata <- lapply(split(mydata, mydata$group),
                  subset, year > 2006 & any(year <= 2006))
newdata <- do.call(rbind, newdata)

row.names(newdata) <- NULL
newdata
#    group value year
#1 Element 1   4.1 2018
#2 Element 1   3.9 2017
#3 Element 1   3.4 2016
```

**DATA.**

```
mydata <-
structure(list(group = c("Element 1", "Element 1", "Element 1", 
"Element 1", "Element 2", "Element 2", "Element 2"), value = c("4.1", 
"3.9", "3.4", "2.1", "2.1", "1", "1"), year = c("2018", "2017", 
"2016", "1996", "2018", "2017", "2008")), row.names = c(NA, -7L
), class = "data.frame")
```